# Why controller inside template is not destroy if it listen to $rootScope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

It look like a bug but my question is why this happened? look to the code below in $stateProvider if a controller defined in template is listening to an event on $rooScope this controller will not destroy even if the state is changed and new controller will be create every time same state

```
<base href="/">

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <a href="#/page1"> page1 </a> 
  <a href="#/page2"> page2 </a>
  <a href ng-click="clicked()"> broadcast</a>

  <div ui-view> </div>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function ($stateProvider) {

$stateProvider
.state('search', {
    url: '/page1',
    templateUrl: '/page1.html',
    controller: 'testCtrl'
})

.state('/', {
  url: '/page2',
  templateUrl: '/page2.html'
})
})

 .controller('MainCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){
   $scope.clicked = function(){
      $rootScope.$broadcast('hi')
   }
 })

.controller('SecondCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){
  $rootScope.$on('hi', function(){
   console.log('SecondCtrl: hi broadcast received' + new Date())
  })
})
```

I know this problem can be solve by listen to $scope instead of $rootScope but my question is what is the behind the scene reason? because it could happened in other case that listen to rootScope is important.

simple of output ofter many clicks between page1 and page2 then broadcast

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug.

When you call `$rootScope.$on` it registers a listener on `$rootScope`. It has no way of knowing from which controller you called `$on`, and so it doesn't know that according to the design of your app, when the controller is removed that listener should also be removed.

So, the controller will need to manually clean up after itself by listening to the `$destroy` event on its local `$scope`, and calling the deregistration function returned by the initial call to `$rootScope.$on`:

```
.controller('SecondCtrl', function($rootScope, $scope){
  var deregister = $rootScope.$on('hi', function(){
    console.log('SecondCtrl: hi broadcast received' + new Date())
  });
  $scope.$on('$destroy', deregister);
})
```

Comment: Thanks this exactly what I missed